# Why my WordPress Site Asking for HTTP Authentication?

Tags: htaccess

currently i was working on a client website and when when ever i try to open wp-Admin page its displaying an authentication box.After discussing the current situation with hosting provider they replied that

> we have put an extra layer of protection on all pages of this
>   website

But when i requested to remove this protection their reply was

> The permission of .htaccess file is set to 0755. I have changed the
>   permission to 0644 and added the code to .htaccess file. After saving
>   the file and loading wp-admin page the file permission was
>   automatically changed back to 0755 and the code was removed from the
>   .htaccess file.

Their 2nd reply was

> The issue is that we are not allowed to edit the .htaccess file. It
>   seems like the file mvf.php is not allowing to edit the .htaccess
>   file. Please inform your developer to edit the said file and add the
>   code in to .htaccess file to remove the authentication dialogue box.

BUt and when i added the above mention code soon after refreshing the page the authentication again automatically applied so when i discussed this situation with hosting provider

their reply was.

> file mvf.php is changing the behavior of your .htaccess file. If this
>   file was not uploaded by your developer it could be uploaded by
>   someone else and could be a malicious file. If you are unaware of this
>   file please follow the steps below to remove the malicious contents
>   from the server. Make sure that you remove any unwanted/unknown
>   file/folder from the host and download all the files to your local
>   machine and scan them for any malware and upload a clean copy of your
>   website.

Now i do not know what to do because issue still not resolved and my client blaming on me because of this issue.

I,M in Trouble and Need serious Guideline from top level word press developers in this regards thank you very much

Comment: They say "please follow the steps below to remove the malicious contents from the server". Did you follow those steps?

Comment: they just sent me a website link where multiple soultions were mentioned like one was to restore your website, or scan your contant etc and none of them worked for me.They did not mention any specific solution for this specifi problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK

1. Back up the files and MySQL
2. Delete mvf.php
3. Try editing .htaccess again and see if it works.

You can also try opening the mvf.php and seeing what's in there. You can also try installing a security plugin like WordFence to scan your site, but I'd do a full malware clean up. WordFence offers that as well if you don't know how.

Comment: thank you very much for providing this solution,i will surely try  this method and update you later